# Microdata: How to indicate multiple awards in the UL tag?

Tags: microdata

I wonder if we can repeat the same itemprop in the same itemtype, e.g.:

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
   <li itemprop="award">Award 1</li>
   <li itemprop="award">Award 2</li>
   <li itemprop="award">Award 3</li>
</ul>
```

Is this a right way to specify awards using Microdata? How about the use of the itemprop **awards** instead? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fine as you wrote it, multiple values are allowed in microdata.

I find [this](http://foolip.org/microdatajs/live/) handy to test this kind of stuff. It extracts all the awards from your snippets, so it's good!

As you can see [in the schema.org documentation](http://schema.org/Person), `awards` is a legacy spelling and should no longer be used.

**Update**: Oh and welcome to StackOverflow by the way :-)